# Where did cv.smooth() go? I can't find an equivalent in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Why hasn't cv.smooth() been ported to cv2? All my google searches bring me to cv2.blur() which is not at all the same thing, or erosion / dilation which is close but not close enough.

Is there something I'm missing? Has it been renamed? Is it hiding somewhere else?

EDIT:

```
cv2.medianBlur()
```

seems to do what I want, but not quite as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here citation from [documentation of Smooth()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#smooth): "Note The function is now obsolete. Use GaussianBlur(), blur(), medianBlur() or bilateralFilter()."

If you used Smooth with default parameters than means that you used Gaussian blur, i.e. [GaussianBlur()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur) is the one you are looking for.